# TSAlertView enables device rotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, rotation, uialertview

Because I needed a more custom UIAlertView, I'm using. My problem ist that it enables the device rotation in any direction, even if I have disabled it.

Before the AlertView shows up, the Landscape Mode is deactivated, but when I call show, any direction is possible.

What's going on here? I don't have this behavior with a UIAlertView.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `@implementation TSAlertViewController` and check `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`

```
@implementation TSAlertViewController
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}
```